Error with uno module when using unoconv for file conversion in Python: 'Cannot find a suitable pyuno library' despite venv setup
I only have problems with my new project. I want to build a file converter.
I am doing this with Python and LibreOffice.  I have installed everything, but it always gives me an error message with uno, although I have inhaled it. With Python, I actually always need venv.
I once asked ChatGPT for a Python script:
import subprocess
import os

def convert_pdf_to_odt(pdf_file):
    # Überprüfen, ob die Datei existiert
    if not os.path.exists(pdf_file):
        print(f"Die Datei {pdf_file} wurde nicht gefunden.")
        return

    # Zielpfad: gleiche Datei mit der Endung .odt
    output_file = os.path.splitext(pdf_file)[0] + '.odt'

    try:
        # Verwende unoconv, um das PDF in ODT zu konvertieren
        subprocess.run(['unoconv', '-f', 'odt', pdf_file], check=True)
        print(f"Erfolgreich konvertiert: {pdf_file} -> {output_file}")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Fehler bei der Konvertierung: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Beispiel-PDF-Datei (Pfad zur Datei anpassen)
    pdf_file = '/home/ben/convert-commander/test/pdfs/Bild4.pdf'
    
    # Konvertiere die PDF-Datei in ODT
    convert_pdf_to_odt(pdf_file)

When executing, it gives me the error message:
unoconv: Cannot find a suitable pyuno library and python binary combination in /usr/lib/libreoffice
ERROR: No module named 'uno'

unoconv: Cannot find a suitable office installation on your system.
ERROR: Please locate your office installation and send your feedback to:
       http://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv/issues
Fehler bei der Konvertierung: Command '['unoconv', '-f', 'odt', '/home/ben/convert-commander/test/pdfs/Bild4.pdf']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

As I said, I am in a venv
Can you help me?
Thanks!
(translated with deepl from german)
